# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'http://localhost:8888'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am facing an issue with Spring cloud. The used versions are,

**Spring boot version: 2.4.4
Spring cloud version: 2020.0.2**

Your input will help me to resolve the microservice startup issue.

I have a spring cloud config server which pick the data from repository and the endpoint

http://localhost:8888/xyz-service/default returning data.

I am trying to read the configuration from microservice which fails to connect to the config server, please refer below error

```
13:25:09.887 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888*'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:217)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at com.microservice.limitmicroservice.LimitMicroserviceApplication.main(LimitMicroserviceApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferencesForFile(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:122)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you provide your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I see the person did not answer, I have two different applications. They have the same config and the same POM but one gives me this error.
This is the config for both applications, both uses spring boot version 2.4.4, uses java 11, spring cloud 2020.0.2

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
spring.jmx.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

but the second one fails with similar the error than above
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'optional:configserver:'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following dependency in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this problem is that spring boot does not know how to read the configuration from (for example) repository on github. To solve this problem, you should check whether the following dependency exists in the corresponding module (versions can be different) :

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:3.1.5'
```

Connecting this starter should solve your problem